# Why does code in static block execute multiple times?

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, connection, javers

I have created a class in Spring boot to establish a global javers object that can be used by all classes. This is my code.

```
@Component
public class JaversInstance {

    public static final Javers javers;
    static
    {

        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new ConnectionProvider() {
            @Override
            public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
                String url = "any_url";
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("user", "test");
                props.setProperty("password", "test");
                DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
                System.out.println("CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked");
                return DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
            }
        };

        JaversSqlRepository sqlRepository = SqlRepositoryBuilder
                .sqlRepository()
                .withConnectionProvider(connectionProvider)
                .withDialect(DialectName.MYSQL).build();
        System.out.println("JAVERS instance creation");
        javers = JaversBuilder.javers().registerJaversRepository(sqlRepository).build();
    }

    private JaversInstance() {

    }

}
```

Output:

```
JAVERS instance creation
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
CONNECTION PROVIDER invoked
```

Can someone tell me what has happened here. Why the getConnection() is called so many times? Is this any kind of retry?

Comment: Don’t use static initializers unless you have very good reason to.  Put the code elsewhere.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you please suggest a better way to establish a global javers object that can be used by all classes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using Spring, just make it a singleton Spring bean. Inject it wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens as many times as the anonymous class of `ConnectionProvider` is loaded. The following code will help you understand it better:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    static Comparator<Integer> comparator;
    static {
        comparator = new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(40);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(30);
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: I could get this. But in my code, I have called the connectionProvider only once when initializing JaversSqlRepository. Then how is it called multiple times. Can you please explain in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `ConnectionProvider` is instantiated inside a static block, its overridden method is neither `static` (can't be) nor related to the static block itself but to the instance `connectionProvider`.

Basically, you implement a method of an anonymous class. I suppose the `ConnectionProvider` is an interface, then defining a class implementing the very same interface would be effectively the same as your code:

```
static
{
    ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new MyConnectionProvider();
}
```

The internals of the `getConnection` method is not bound to the static block, the instance `connectionProvider` itself is. There are multiple calls since the method has been invoked multiple times from an instance defined within the static block.